# Private Pod not gets Linted because of `use_frameworks! in podfile

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, jitsi

ScreenShots:

[image: Compiling]

> While compiling my private pod  i am getting this error 
>   (Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it. The Swift Pod being used is: VideoLib) during validation.

, eventhough i added use_frameworks! in my podfile  still i  am getting this error

> Here is the attached google drive  link which contain the  source code of private pod project  ,have a look at this and please let me know  in case what causing the pod  get failed in linting [VideoLib.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByfGsc0AQJ0kX1l0a2xuV0xBa1k/view?usp=sharing)